# Why in multiple connections to PricesResource Publisher, only one gets the stream?

Tags: jax-rs, rx-java, rx-java2, resteasy, quarkus

It seems that only one http client gets the stream of data, while the others do not.

Is it true that the Publisher is hot data, and that it should broadcast to all subscribers?

Please find more in [Can I allow multiple http clients to consume a Flowable stream of data with resteasy-rxjava2 / quarkus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896505/can-i-allow-multiple-http-clients-to-consume-a-flowable-stream-of-data-with-rest)

```
package org.acme.kafka;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.SseElementType;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Channel;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static io.reactivex.Flowable.fromIterable;

/**
 * A simple resource retrieving the "in-memory" "my-data-stream" and sending the items to a server sent event.
 */
@Path("/migrations")
public class StreamingResource {
    private volatile Map<String, String> counterBySystemDate = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Inject
    @Channel("migrations")
    Flowable<String> counters;

    @GET
    @Path("/stream")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS) // denotes that server side events (SSE) will be produced
    @SseElementType("text/plain") // denotes that the contained data, within this SSE, is just regular text/plain data
    public Publisher<String> stream() {
        Flowable<String> mainStream = counters.doOnNext(dateSystemToCount -> {
            String key = dateSystemToCount.substring(0, dateSystemToCount.lastIndexOf("_"));
            counterBySystemDate.put(key, dateSystemToCount);
        });
        return fromIterable(counterBySystemDate.values().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .concatWith(mainStream)
                .onBackpressureLatest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information of what you are doing? Code snippet, extension list, the content of your `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Replay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) operator or [ConnectableObservable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I did then was to inject the messages coming on the Flowable into a PublishSubject pipe and apply a backpressure strategy, thus offering a broadcast downstream.