# Can I allow multiple http clients to consume a Flowable stream of data with resteasy-rxjava2 / quarkus?

Tags: jax-rs, rx-java, rx-java2, resteasy, quarkus

Currently I am able to see the streaming values exposed by the code below, but only one http client will receive the continuous stream of values, the others will not be able to.
The code, a modified version of the quarkus quickstart for kafka reactive streaming is:

```
@Path("/migrations")
public class StreamingResource {
    private volatile Map<String, String> counterBySystemDate = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Inject
    @Channel("migrations")
    Flowable<String> counters;

    @GET
    @Path("/stream")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS) // denotes that server side events (SSE) will be produced
    @SseElementType("text/plain") // denotes that the contained data, within this SSE, is just regular text/plain data
    public Publisher<String> stream() {
        Flowable<String> mainStream = counters.doOnNext(dateSystemToCount -> {
            String key = dateSystemToCount.substring(0, dateSystemToCount.lastIndexOf("_"));
            counterBySystemDate.put(key, dateSystemToCount);
        });
        return fromIterable(counterBySystemDate.values().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .concatWith(mainStream)
                .onBackpressureLatest();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make any modification that would allow multiple clients to consume the same data, in a broadcast fashion?

I guess this implies letting go of backpressure, because that would imply a state per consumer?

I saw that Observable is not accepted as a return type in the resteasy-rxjava2 for the Server Side Events media-tpe.

Please let me know any ideas,

Thank you

Please find the full code in [Why in multiple connections to PricesResource Publisher, only one gets the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876986/why-in-multiple-connections-to-pricesresource-publisher-only-one-gets-the-strea)